# Howto copy a folder and all its content in Java recursively, including symbolic links

Tags: unix, symlink, aix, java-6

Currently, using Java 6, I copy a folder and all its content recursively by using FileUtils.copyDirectory().  But that fails (on AIX) because of symbolic links. In particular, one subfolder holds the symbolic link

```
$ ll javaws
lrwxrwxrwx    1 me   staff            13 Feb 21 13:11 javaws -> ../bin/javaws
>>>>> me@machine: /home/me/runtime/jvm/jre/bin <<<<<
```

I can copy the entire folder hierarchy on AIX with the command "cp -rh".  W/o the -r option, cp fails with the same problem as FileUtils.copyDirectory() (There are too many levels of symbolic links to translate a path name.)  I haven't tested it.  But I suppose the issue is present on other Unix variants, too.

As mentioned above FileUtils does not work.  Calling "cp -rh" from Java is no solution either: I need a solution that works across many Unix and Linux variants and would prefer a Java solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy a directory while preserving symlinks using Java File/IO APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024820/copy-a-directory-while-preserving-symlinks-using-java-file-io-apis)